# rapidxml using the where() function

Tags: c++, rapidxml

How is it I use the where() function?

```
    using namespace rapidxml;
    xml_document<> doc;
    std:string xmlfile = "test.xml";
    std::ifstream file ( xmlfile );
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf ( );
    file.close ( );
    std::string content ( buffer.str ( ) );

    try
    {
        doc.parse<0> ( &content [ 0 ] );
    }

    catch ( rapidxml::parse_error& e )
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing error: " << e.what ( ) << "\n";
        //const Ch* e.where ( );
    }
```

got the what() but was looking to get some kind of indicator from where() like the last node that broke the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the RapidXml `where()` metohd, try something like this:

```
std::cout << e.where<char>();
```

Because `where` returns a pointer into the raw XML data, it's a templated function. You can use the returned pointer and the original data to determine a line and column position by counting newlines.